# PHP PDO - почему ошибка Invalid parameter number

Tags: php, pdo

Подскажите в чем ошибка? Пока не могу понять

```
$query = "INSERT INTO `source` (files, nme, hash, hashdat) VALUES (?,?,?,?) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE files = files + :files, nme = nme + :nme, itermy = itermy +1;";
        $stmt = $pdo->prepare($query);
try {
    $pdo->beginTransaction();
  foreach ($source_array as $keys => $row)
  
  {     $stmt->bindParam(':files', $row['files'], PDO::PARAM_INT, 10);
        $stmt->bindParam(':nme', $row['nme'], PDO::PARAM_INT, 15);
        $stmt->bindParam(':hash', $row['hash'], PDO::PARAM_STR, 11);
        $stmt->bindParam(':hashdat', $keys, PDO::PARAM_STR, 20);
        $stmt->execute();
    }
    $pdo->commit();
}catch (Exception $e){
    $pdo->rollback();
    throw $e;
}
```

Выдает ошибку:

Fatal error: Uncaught PDOException: SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: mixed named and positional parameters in C:\test.php

Comment: потому что **mixed named and positional parameters**

Comment: Поменял на одного типа, но все равно ошибка
$query = 'INSERT INTO `source` (files, nme, hash, hashdat) VALUES (:files,:nme,:hash,:hashdat) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE files = files + :files, nme = nme + :nme, itermy = itermy + 1;';

Comment: Во-первых, **не такая же!** Ради бога, учитесь читать ошибки **целиком!** во-вторых, при выключенном режиме эмуляци повторное использование одного и того же именованного плейсхолдера не допускается.

Comment: в данном случае, чтобы обратиться к значению, переданному  в insert, можно использовать values(),  files = files + values(files)

Comment: Понял. Спасибо.